# Dynamically add schema to sqlalchemy func

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import func

data = db.session.query(func.your_schema.your_function_name()).all()
```

I have two schemas which have the same function. In this scenario, how can I dynamically pass the schema name to func?